# Can't validate form with modal in 2 level deep ng-include

Tags: angularjs, forms

**I have this modal in a ng-include inside a template which is also ng-included**

The form inside the modal is :

```
  <div class="input-group form-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.first_name" name="first_name"  class="form-control" placeholder="First name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>

  <div class="input-group form-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>

  <div class="input-group form-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" name = "email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email adress" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">

      <div ng-show="register_form.$submitted || register_form.email.$touched">
        <span ng-show="register_form.email.$error.required">Tell us your email.</span>
        <span ng-show="register_form.email.$error.email">This is not a valid email.</span>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group form-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password1" name = "password1" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>

  <div class="input-group form-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password2" name = "password2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Keep me updated
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <small>
    By signing up, you agree on the <u> <a href="#" class="modalLink">Terms of use</a></u> and the <u><a href="#" class="modalLink">Privacy policies</a></u> of this site.
  </small>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign up</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  Already a member? Sign in <u><a data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".login-modal" class="modalLink" href="">here</a></u>
```

My controller :

```
  $scope.registerNew = function(user){
      console.log(user);
    };
```

I'm trying to do form validation but nothing seems to work.
Can you help me through this ?

Comment: Let's try validating only the Email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `<input type="email">` rather than `<input type="text">` for email field. Use

```
<form novalidate>
<input type="email">
</form>
```

In this case Angular Js will do your email validation. "novalidate" is to turn off the browser validation.